# Why is my function not defined

Tags: python, object

I am new to python and for the life of me I cannot find out why or how my function is not defined. This might be a stupid question and I apologize but I am really stuck and cannot test/fix the rest of this until I get this part working. Any help is appreciated.
Here is my main class which calls the scanner but then my issue is why isn't getChar() not being called. The deepest part of the stack trace told me that nextChar = getChar() was not defined.

```
from Scanner import scanner
from Constants import *

def main():
  python = scanner()
  token = python.scanner()
  while token.tokenType != END_OF_FILE:
      print(token.tokenType, " ", token.lexeme)
      token = python.scanner()


main()




class TokenRec(object):

def __init__(self, tokenType, lexeme, line, col):
    self.tokenType = tokenType
    self.lexeme = lexeme
    self.line = line
    self.col = col


class scanner():


# Constructor for the Scanner class
def __init__(self):
    self.fileName = input("Enter the file name: ")
    self.infile = open(self.fileName, "r")
    self.fChar = self.infile.read(1)
    self.line = 0
    self.col = 0

# gets the next character out of the file
def getChar():
    nextChar = file.read(1)
    if nextChar == "":
        nextChar = '\34'

    return nextChar


# adds the next character onto the lexeme buffer
def addChar(nextToken, nextChar):
    nextToken.lexeme += nextChar


def isKeyWord(nextChar):

    return True

def isSingleToken(nextChar):

    return True

def isMultiToken(nextChar):

    return True


def scanner(self):

    while True:

        nextToken = TokenRec("","",self.line,self.col)
        nextChar = getChar()
        if nextChar == '\n':
            self.line += 1
        self.col = 0

        if nextChar.isalpha():
            addChar(nextToken, nextChar)
            nextChar = getChar()

            while nextChar != " ":
                nextToken.lexeme += nextChar
                nextChar = getChar()
            if nextChar.issspace():
                if isKeyWord(nextChar):
                    print("Error")
                    #Part 2
                else:
                    nextToken.tokenType = 33

        elif nextChar.isdigit():
            nextToken.lexeme = nextChar
            nextChar = getChar()
            while nextChar != " ":
                nextToken.lexeme += nextChar
                nextChar = getChar()
            nextToken.tokenType = 75

        elif nextChar is '"':
            nextChar = getChar()
            while nextChar != '"':
                nextToken.lexeme += nextChar
                nextChar = getChar()

        elif isSingleToken(nextChar):
            print("Error")
            # Part 2

        elif nextChar is '#':

            comment = file.readline()

        elif nextChar is None:
            nextToken.tokenType = 99
            nextToken.lexeme = "END OF FILE"

        else:
            print("Character is illegal or unknown")
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace of the error! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, please post the full stack trace and also, please don't forget your indentation!

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/diessner/Documents/Benedictine/Fall_2014/CMSC 385/Project2/Driver.py", line 17, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/diessner/Documents/Benedictine/Fall_2014/CMSC 385/Project2/Driver.py", line 11, in main
    token = python.scanner()
  File "/Users/diessner/Documents/Benedictine/Fall_2014/CMSC 385/Project2/Scanner.py", line 55, in scanner
    nextChar = getChar(self)
NameError: name 'getChar' is not defined` I believe it was because I did not specify enough like my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Literally minutes after posting this I found my answer. All I had to do was define getChar() as scanner.getChar(). If this is not the correct way or if I am still missing something please feel free to help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that your function is defined within another class.

For example:

```
>>> class foo:
...     @staticmethod
...     def bar():
...             print 'foo+bar = foobar'
... 
>>> bar()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'bar' is not defined
>>> foo().bar()
foo+bar = foobar
>>>
```

Comment: Yes that was it or thats what I found like I said in the answer I posted. Sometimes it just helps writing it out and explaining it.

Comment: Oh oops I hadn't seen your answer yet, glad you figured it out!